# How to manage multiple scenes / screens on AndEngine for Android

Tags: andengine

Do you know if there is any tutorial or example out there showing how to handle multiple screens / scenes of a game?

For example, imagine I have a game with this structure:

- Cover
- Main menu
- Gameplay
- Credits

To put allthe code in just one java file might be a nightmare... I'd like to use different classes and probably different scenes, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extend `Scene` class for all of these scenes. Make a class called `SceneManager`, make a field of this class in your `BaseGameActivity` implementation. The scene manager has fields for all of the scenes, and you can make methods like `SceneManager.getCreditsScene()`, `SceneManager.getMenuScene()` and so on.

This way each scene has it's own file-class, while another classtakes care of all of the scenes and the game activity itself just calls simple methods to access these scenes.

Comment: hi, to do the SceneManager.getCreditsScene(), the scene manager must contain static methods right?

Answer (score 0):

This is the tutorial you are looking for, it's a plataform game, it has a scene manager class taht handles, spalsh, menu, loading and game scenes. It also privdes a Resources Manager that is used to load and unload resources according the scene you are at.

- Main page: http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-1.html
- Scene Manager page: http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-4.html

Comment: These links no longer work